# Assertion failed: lhs.cols() == rhs.rows() && "invalid matrix product"

Tags: c++, codeblocks, eigen, matrix-multiplication

Hey I'm trying to multiply 2 matrixes, I kind of know what's my problem is, it's that I'm trying to multiply a **2x1 matrix** by **NxN matrix**, but NxN is the same size as 2x1! So how do I solve that?

this is my code:

```
MatrixXf dmap_return(MatrixXf& in)
{
    MatrixXf out(in.rows(),in.cols());
    float val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.rows(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < in.cols(); j++)
        {
            val = in(i, j);
            out(i, j) = dsigmoid(val);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
    MatrixXf output_errors = targets - outputs;
    std::cout << output_errors << std::endl << std::endl;;
    MatrixXf gradients = dmap_return(outputs);
    std::cout << gradients << std::endl << std::endl;;

    gradients *= output_errors; // it crushes here
```

`output_errors` is a 2x1 matrix and so is `gradients`

Here is a screenshot of the error I get when I run the program:

[image]

I'm trying to keep this example as simple as I can but please let me know if you need additional code.

Comment: Before calling the problematic `operator*=`, verify the size of the two matrix objects as being equal yourself.

Comment: The only matrix multiply allowed is with sizes `axN` and `Nxb` in this order. So, `2x1` by `2x1`is invalid.

Comment: Why is it invalid? is there a way around this? @Ripi2

Comment: @yarinCohen it's invalid because thats the way matrix multiplication works if you try to multiply 2 matrixes of sizes  `MxN` by `NxQ` the 2 "inner" dimensions `N` must be equal.

Comment: Using paper and pencil write any matrix A 3x2 and B 3x2. Then try to multiply A·B. If you think you did well, try with B·A. If you still think you did well, read a goob book about matrix maths.

Comment: well that's odd, I'm rewriting a Backpropagation that is originally written in js in The Coding Train channel, and it compiled perfectly from him. with the same parameters, only different was that he implemented a Matrix class himself

Comment: If you want an element-wise product, try the `Eigen::Array` class.

Answer (score 0):

**Math:**

3 Matrices A, B, C.

A: n x m (rows x cols)
B: m x p
C: n x p

*In words:* the result matrix has the same num rows as A and the same num cols of B, further, num rows of A has to be equal to the num cols of B.

Each field of C is the result of the dot product of the related row of A and col of B.

**Code:**

The following code assumes that the matrices have the `operator ()(size_t row, size_t col)` implemented.

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
C& mult_matrix(const A& a, const B& b, C& c) noexcept
{
    assert(a.cols() == b.rows());
    assert(c.rows() == a.rows());
    assert(c.cols() == b.cols());

    size_t n = a.rows();
    size_t m = a.cols();
    size_t p = b.cols();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < p; ++j) {
            c(i,j) = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < m; ++k) {
                c(i,j) += (a(i,k) * b(k,j));
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```